# CSS: Hover effect has to be initialised with "click"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have read the answers on this question: [CSS Hover effect only on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168651/css-hover-effect-only-on-click). I have a bootstrap4 `dropdown-menu` and I have added a `hover effect` over it to display `dropdown-items`.

```css
.my-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline;
}

.my-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    border-style: none!important;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)!important;
}

.my-menu ul li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-menu">
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="" class="pr-2 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Register</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The hover effect is working but it needs a `click` to get initialized & I have no idea why it does that.

Either Bootstrap4 Dropdowns don't work properly with hover effect or I am doing something wrong. The first solution that came into my mind is to build my own `dropdown-menu` from scratch; but i wanted to come here to see if i can get a quick fix.

Comment: You need to give the li element a position: relative property.

Comment: it worked, thank you ! do you want to post that as an answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `li` element a `position: relative` property.

```
.my-menu ul li {
    position: relative;
}
```